# How to replace componentWillReceiveProps in react native application?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have heard that componentWillRecieveProps lifecycle method is not a good option to use in react native project,instead use getDerivedStateFromProps.
So i tried to replace my componentWillRecieveProps with getDerivedStateFromProps.But i dont know to to do it, i tried with componentDidUpdate() but it calls setstate repeatedly.

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

  if(nextProps.shopList.isFetching===false) {
        this.setState({isLoading:false})
    if(!_.isEqual(nextProps.shopList, this.props.shopList) && nextProps.shopList.error===false ) {
       this.formatShops(nextProps.shopList.shops)
     } else {

    }
  } else {
    this.setState({isLoading:true})
  }


  if(nextProps.common.isFetching===false) {

    this.setState({isLoading:false})
    if(nextProps.common.error===false) {
      if(!_.isEqual(nextProps.common, this.props.common) && nextProps.common.error===false ) {
       if(nextProps.common.otpverifysucess==false) {
            this.props.navigation.dispatch(logoutAction);
      }
     }
    }
  }
  }
```

This is my entire componentWillRecieveProps.Can anyone help to move it to getDerivedStateFromProps lifecycle method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is, put all the state update part in `getDerivedStateFromProps` method and put all the action based on difference between new props and old props values in `componentDidUpdate` method. `componentDidUpdate` will get prevProps values as a argument and `this.props` will have the new props value.

**To replace the `componentWillReceiveProps` by `componentDidUpdate`:**

So if you are replacing the `componentWillReceiveProps` with `componentDidUpdate`, replace `nextProps` with `this.props` and `this.props` with `prevProps`.

> `nextProps` (argument to componentWillReceiveProps) to `this.props` (in `componentDidUpdate`)
>
> `this.props` (inside componentDidUpdate) to `prevProps` (in `componentDidUpdate`)

Try this code:

```
getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if(nextProps.shopList.isFetching === false || nextProps.common.isFetching === false) {
    return { isLoading: false }
  } else {
    return { isLoading: true }
  }
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(this.props.shopList.isFetching === false) {
    if(!_.isEqual(this.props.shopList, prevProps.shopList) && this.props.shopList.error === false ) {
      this.formatShops(this.props.shopList.shops)
    }
  }

  if(this.props.common.error === false && this.props.common.isFetching === false) {
    if(!_.isEqual(this.props.common, prevProps.common) && this.props.common.error === false) {
      if(this.props.common.otpverifysucess == false) {
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(logoutAction);
      }
    }
  }
}
```